# Конфигурирование окна

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сконфигурировать окно tk.Tk()?

задача:
убрать кнопки свернуть, развернуть, закрыть, текст и иконку,
оставить окно и рамку окна, задать ей цвет и размер.

псевдокод:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(...)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root.configure(highlightthickness=5, highlightcolor='green', 
highlightbackground='green')
root.overrideredirect(1)
```